# How to position an imageview 1/3 of the way down the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an image view be placed about 1/3 of the way down the screen, and, on
top of that, I need it to work on multiple devices, so it can't just be a set dp value. I don't mind wether it's using a RelativeLayout of a ConstraitLayout. Here's the image code:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_100"/>
```

Does anyone know how to achive this? Let me know if you have any questions on my question :)

**Edit:**

@Fede Cana

I tried your answer with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/continueOuterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it shows up like this:

[image]

The arrow and the light blue square shows where I want it to be, if that makes sense :)

**Edit 2:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll add an image if Fede Cana's answer doesn't work for me. I'm just trying it out at the moment.

Comment: Look at my modified answer, is this the way you want it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but um no, imagne if you put two lines across the screen the split it into 3 equal parts, and then on the 1st line putting the imageview on the middle of it. See my edited question for reference :)

Comment: Sorry if that sounds super confusing!

Comment: Look now and let me know please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/continueOuterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3333"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tag"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but see my edit on my question please

Comment: A vertical bias in a constraint layout would have also done the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical bias attribute which tells the layout how to place a view between the constrained views vertically same for horizontal bias.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/continueOuterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```